# Implement simple Photo Gallery like iPhone's 'Photos' with UIScrollView and UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I have an UIScrollView which populated with UIImageView. I'd like to have each UIImageView to be able to zoom & pan, and flick to the next page, just like iPhone's Photos app. I have searched around and what I have so far is this:

```
NSArray *pages = [self loadImages];

_pageScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
NSUInteger pageCount = [pages count]; // Adjustable
for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {

    CGFloat x = i * self.view.frame.size.width;

    // Page Settings
    UIImageView *pageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    pageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    pageView.image = [pages objectAtIndex:i];
    pageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    pageView.tag = i;

    UIScrollView *pageScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    pageScroll.maximumZoomScale = 2.0f;
    pageScroll.minimumZoomScale = 1.0f;
    pageScroll.zoomScale = 1.0f;
    pageScroll.bouncesZoom = YES;
    pageScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(pageView.frame.size.width, pageView.frame.size.height);
    pageScroll.pagingEnabled = NO;
    pageScroll.delegate = self;
    [pageScroll addSubview:pageView];

    // Gesture Reocgnisers
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGr = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pinchImage:)];
    pinchGr.delegate = self;
    [pageView addGestureRecognizer:pinchGr];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGr = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panImage:)];
    [pageView addGestureRecognizer:panGr];

    [_pageScrollView addSubview:pageView];

}
_pageScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * pageCount, self.view.frame.size.height);

_pageScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

_pageScrollView.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:_pageScrollView];
```

They just work fine for just paging (horizontal scrolling). However, I'm stack at how to implement UIGestures for each UIImageView. And with the help from various good questions & answers here in stackoverflow, I have implemented Zoom & Pan like this:

```
- (void) pinchImage:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)pgr {

  [self adjustAnchorPointForGestureRecognizer:pgr];

  if ([pgr state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [pgr state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

    CGFloat currentScale = pgr.view.frame.size.width / pgr.view.bounds.size.width;
    CGFloat newScale = currentScale * pgr.scale;

    if (newScale < 1.01f) {
        newScale = 1.01f;
    }
    if (newScale > 3.0f) {
        newScale = 3.0f;
    }

    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(newScale, newScale);
    pgr.view.transform = transform;
    pgr.scale = 1;
  }
}

- (void) panImage:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)panGr {

  if ([panGr state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [panGr state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

    CGPoint p = [panGr translationInView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"[PAMPHLET PAGE]: Point: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(p));
    CGPoint movedPoint = CGPointMake(panGr.view.center.x + p.x, panGr.view.center.y + p.y);

    if (panGr.view.frame.size.width > panGr.view.center.x + p.x &&
        panGr.view.frame.size.height > panGr.view.center.y + p.y) {
        panGr.view.center = movedPoint;
        NSLog(@"Current: %f / %f", panGr.view.center.x, panGr.view.center.y);
    }

    [panGr setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];
  }
}
```

This works almost there, but has several problems. Both Zoom & Pan is not limited to the scale of UIImageView, and when zoomed out or pan out to the outside of bounds, the image exceeds to the next view and everything gone wrong. I'm still figuring out this but don't know where should I start this.

How can I 'limit' those gesture's effective area, or should I try another method? Is this even the right approach to achieve this? I just wanted to make simple photo gallery like Photos app...

Please, any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use MWPhotoBrowser from [here](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser), it will take care of downloading remote images too in addition to functionalities you are expecting.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer! Actually, I tried MWPhotoBrowser and it was good. But I need to customise navbar extensively and customising MWPhotoBrowser is too hard for me. So I needed to implement this behaviour on my own. Thanks anyway!

Comment: After a week and I finally got this working (well, almost). I did it by nesting UIScrollViews. Sadly no one here couldn't help me and didn't even noticed the question... I accept 
Paramasivan Samuttiram's suggestion as he is the only one gave me some attention. Thank you!

Comment: @FaustV please can you share your solution. Thank you.